# MOSS - Document Library - Quick Part - HTML Content

Tags: 2007, list, workflow

I am using sharepoint 2007. My situation is users input into a custom list. A workflow will copy this list item into a document library with the same structure (except the rich text field is a muti-line field).

I customized the word template to use these fields using quick parts -> document property.

Looks great except the html from the rich text box has all the html markup from the rich text field. I was hoping it would sort of convert the html to word formatting similarly to copying and pasting from a web site to word.

Question: Is there a way to accomplish this using the build-in sharepoint/word stuff? I am thinking I may have to make a custom workflow in VS and strip out html formatting, but it would be nice not to have to do this and have word do it automagically.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks and have a great day! Ryan

Comment: I have the same question, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This question actually has two parts.

**1. How do you get a Document Library to support rich text fields?**

Answer: http://www.sharepointsingh.com/2010/07/add-multiline-rich-textenhanced-rich.html

If you follow the steps on that site, you should be able to figure out how to get rich text fields in the document library. Viewing document(item) properties in Sharepoint will show you the rich text, and you can even edit the item with Sharepoint's rich text editor.

**2. How do you get Microsoft Word to import the columns from Sharepoint?**

Answer: None yet... :(

Now, the phrasing of this question may need some refinement. If you followed the answer to question 1, you can now create a new document (from the Sharepoint Document Library). Inside of Microsoft Word, the columns you created in Sharepoint show up under Quick Parts -> Document Property. Those document properties seem to be ALWAYS formatted as plain text. Even if your Document Library supports rich text columns, Word opens them as plain text.

I am using MS Word 2007, and Sharepoint 2007.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Is it not possible to use rich text content using Quick Parts document property? If so do you have any proof from MSDN saying we can't integrate rich text content in document library with MS word using Quick parts?